# StackOverflowException in DAO

Tags: c#

I am learning about Data Access Object Design Patterns and implementing it with c# / oracle. However when I try to run the program I get an error.

I am simply trying to add data to my database, however I keep getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Test.dll

It happens at my ReviewGame getter and setter.

Would you be so kind to view my code and see where I am going wrong? I would appreciate any help.

```
public string ReviewGame { get; set; }

"insert into review values(review_seq.nextval," + 2+ "," + review.MemberId + ", '"    +review.ReviewGame+ "')";

ReviewDao reviewDao = new ReviewDaoImp();
Review r = new Review();

r.reviewGame = textBox1.Text;
r.ToString();

reviewDao.addReview(r);
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but it looks like you're trying to concatenate an object to a string in your insert statement.  Isn't a Review an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your properties call themselves in their getter and setter. You need to use a backing field to store the data:

```
private string _reviewGame;
public string ReviewGame
{
    get { return _reviewGame; }
    set { _reviewGame = value; }
}
```

Or you can use an auto property:

```
public string ReviewGame { get; set; }
```

(Note that I also changed to property name to start with an upper case, which is according to conventions.)

Comment: Thank you Steven for taking the time to look at my code and answer my question it really helped me. I took your advice and used the auto property format and following naming conventions. That solved the stackoverflow exception. And the issue with me concatenating an object to a string in my insert statement was solved by inserting review.ReviewGame instead of review. Thank you again, it is much appreciated.